# Equivalent of BBEdit on Linux, Win

Tags: text-editor

Can anyone suggest an equivalent of BBEdit for linux and win in terms or multifile search and replace as well as html cleanup, formatting, etc.?

So far I tried NotePad++ and jEdit with limited luck.
Thanks in advance

Comment: ... so I hear it's a great operating system, but lacks a decent editor ;-)

Comment: ... so I hear it can play pong, but lacks a decent editor ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On *nix, the only real equivalent is Vim, with a host of plugins to fill the gap.  I struggled with the same issue and made a [git repo that hold the configs that make Vim more BBedit-like](https://github.com/newalexandria/vim.ana).

The README on the repo will tell you more about the plugins involved.  A script is provided for installation and config.  I am currently reviewing the NERDtree plugin to add doc-browser-like sidebar to the layout.

Comment: I kow it's not cool to do, but THX mate. I love BBEdit and I just stumbled on your answer by accident (I do use vanilla Vim mind you). I 'll definitely give it a go.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing to BBedit that I've seen on Linux is Sublime.

Answer (score 2):

Atom, Sublime and VSCode are very good, modern, and cross platform (all three run on Linux, Windows and Mac):

1. https://atom.io/
2. https://www.sublimetext.com/
3. https://code.visualstudio.com/

They all have a rich package base. In particular, my personal favourite is Sublime, because it is SO fast.

Answer (score 1):

on Windows CodePad

on Linux/Other Vim

on Mac buy BBEdit(I use it)

Answer (score -1):

Notepad++ is my favourite on Windows http://notepad-plus-plus.org/
Nano Editor (http://nano-editor.org) on Linux easy to use works with most common *nix distro's and with Cygwin can also run on Windows.

Notepadqq its a powerhouse like Notepad++, Atom is also good very extensible and LimeText if you can get a port to work.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have a Linux version.

Comment: I am right now useing Notepad++ on Fedora32. Works like a charm with Wine. Mind you, it's not just some crappy adaptation, NPP is open source and the port is flawless.

Comment: There are some good alternatives on Linux try Notepadqq its a powerhouse like Notepad++, Atom is also good very extensible and LimeText if you can get a port to work.

Comment: @webmagnets is that the reason for the downvote I don't think you read my post properly (I have updated it now).